# Android: EditText loses focus when setText is called

Tags: android, timer

I'm creating an Android app which contains a timer that counts down and is displayed in EditTexts. 
There is another EditText on the page that I would like to be able to edit while the timer is counting down.

The problem is that when I call setText() to update the timer text, the other EditText loses focus. Since the timer is updated every second, the soft keyboard is dismissed after less than a second. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

I would like to keep the timer running (on screen) while the keyboard is visible, but I can't find any good answers of how to do this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use TextView, to display the remaining time, and the EditText, where you want to write wont lose focus.

Comment: Edit text.setfocus(true);edittext.requestfocus();    see if this helps

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and `editText.getText().clear()` did the trick for me